# I am getting this error after I run the following code "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException". How can I fix it?

Tags: java, multithreading, fibonacci

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException; 
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService; 
import java.util.concurrent.Executors; 
import java.util.concurrent.Future; 

public class Fibonacci { 


    private static long[] value; 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException { 
        int n;
        try { 
            n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            throw new RuntimeException(" number n"); 
        }

        value = new long[n + 1]; 
        long start = System.nanoTime(); 
        System.out.print("Dynamic Programming = " + fibon(n)); 
        long end = System.nanoTime(); 

        System.out.println("\t time = " + (end - start) + "ns"); 
        start = System.nanoTime(); 

        System.out.print("Sequence = " + Sequence(n));
        end = System.nanoTime(); 

        System.out.println("\t time = " + (end - start) + "ns"); 
        start = System.nanoTime(); 

        //int nThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); 
        int nThreads = 30; 
         ExecutorService executorService = Executors 
                .newFixedThreadPool(nThreads); 
        int result; 
        try { 
            result = fibonacciSum(n, executorService); }
        catch (ExecutionException e) { 
            throw new RuntimeException("Thread Interuppted "); } 

        System.out.print(" MultiThreading = " + result); 
        end = System.nanoTime(); 
        System.out.println("\t time = " + (end - start) + "ns"); 
    } 

    public static long fibon(int n) { 
        value[0] = 1; 
        value[1] = 1; 
            if (n <= 2) 
            return 1;

          else if (value[n - 1] != 0) 
          return value[n]; 

        for (int j = 2; j <= n; j++) { 
           value[j] = fibon(j - 2) + fibon(j - 1); } 
            return value[n]; 
    } 

    public static long Sequence(int n) { 
        if (n <= 2) 
            return 1; 
        else 
            return (Sequence(n - 1) + Sequence(n - 2)); 
    } 

    private static class FibonacciThread implements Runnable { 
        int index; 
        int result; 
        ExecutorService executorService; 
        public FibonacciThread(int index) { 
            this.index = index; 
        } 
         public void run() { 

            try { 
                this.result = fibonacciSum(index, executorService); 
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                throw new RuntimeException("Thread interupted"); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    private static int fibonacciSum(int index, ExecutorService executorService) 
      throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException { 
        if (index == 1 || index == 2) { 
            return 1; 
        } else {   

            FibonacciThread fibonacciThread1 = new FibonacciThread(index - 2); 
            fibonacciThread1.executorService=executorService; 
            Future future = executorService.submit(fibonacciThread1); 
            Object object = future.get(); 
            int resultPart2 = fibonacciSum(index - 1, executorService); 
            int result = fibonacciThread1.result + resultPart2; 
           //executorService.shutdown(); 
           return result; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I am getting this error after I run the above code.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Number n   at
>   Fibonacci.main(Fibonacci.java:16)

Please tell me how to fix this.
This program is suppose to work as follows: On the command line, the user will enter the number of Fibonacci numbers that the program is to generate. The program will then create a separate thread that will generate the Fibonacci numbers, placing the sequence in data that can be shared by the threads (an array is probably the most convenient data structure).

Comment: Make sure that you launch your program with `java Fibonacci <value-of-n>` otherwise you will get this exception since your program excepts one argument

Comment: How do you run your program?  BTW what do you think `throw new RuntimeException(" number n");` do?

Comment: Please reduce your example code to a [mcve].  Minimal code should not normally contain timing routines, unless the question is specifically about that aspect.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running the program you should provide the arguments in the command. Use the following command where "n" should be the integer number of Fibonacci numbers that the program is to generate

*java Fibonacci n*

Answer (score 0):

To read from standard input stream, read from System.in stream. The string array passes to the main method is the command line arguments, not user input data.